# Why there is no badge available to say "Well formatted question" in SFSE?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I am just reviewing the badges from SFSE site. But I can't find no badge is available and awarded for "Well formatted Question"/ "Good Format Question". So does anyone know why?

**Behind Story**:

*Why I am asking means, most of the time we can ask new users to add `What you have tried` and `Where you stuck` questions to know that new user tried method/way for that question and help to overcome the issue. So if any badge available as "Well formatted Question"/ "Good Format Question" and awarded into that users who default added those details means it's will kind of encourage for the new users right?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Badges reward and recognize activity that can be directly measured. There *are* badges that recognize contributions that are well-received by the community, as measured by upvotes. One example is the [Nice Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/badges/20/nice-question) badge, which is awarded for a question voted to +10. Similarly, the [Curious](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/badges/100/curious) badge (and its follow-ups Inquisitive and Socratic) recognize users who maintain a positively-voted question record over time.

There's no way to directly measure a well-asked question other than upvotes, however.

Comment: Well Noted. Thanks a lot @David Reed.